# Load like event in Windows Forms for any control like textbox, checkbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

In Windows Forms when a UserControl or Form first time becomes visible the Load event is fired.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load.aspx

Is there any such event for controls like Checkbox, TextBox, Label ?

Comment: MSDN is your friend (sometimes): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox_events.aspx

Comment: Nope, based on what I can see from MSDN docs. What exactly are you trying to achieve? someone may know how to solve it

Comment: UI is being created using XML. I need to set a controls visibility through events and subscriptions which are also defined in XML. For example to handle ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event, a event publisher is defined for it in XML, there can be other controls defined in XML which will subscribe to this XML. I need some controls to be pre-hidden, if they have a particular subscription defined, I need to fire this subscription code the first time the control is loaded, so I will use such event to fire the subscription code. So basically I need to fire some code whenever the control is loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You could use the HandleCreated event, it is fired when the native window for the control is created.  The first event you can rely on to run after the class constructor ran.  It is triggered when the parent adds the control to its Controls collection and the control becomes visible.

Beware however that it this event can fire more than once.  Controls may be re-created when certain properties get reassigned, the kind that requires the native CreateWindowEx() function to be called with new style flags.  So you'll at least need to carry around a bool flag that keeps track of this.

Also note that setting properties of a control *after* the native window is created is pretty inefficient.  All Winforms controls were designed to allow properties to be set *before* the native window is created.  Whatever code you are generating almost surely should use the class constructor instead.  Either of the derived control itself.  Or in the code of the parent, much like InitializeComponent() does for a form or user-control.

The same is true for the existing Load event.  It tends to be over-used due to the VB6 legacy where the Load event was very important.  In Winforms however it is only required for code that depends on the final location and size of a control or form.  Which may be different from the design properties due to form scaling.  Any other code belongs in the constructor.